# How to display images saved in wwwroot (asp.net core ) in Angular project

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, frontend, backend

I am working at one of my personal project based in ASP.NET CORE and Angular. I can specify that for this project I have two separates projects.

First project is just Server side in Microsoft **Visual Studio** ( back end code, Controllers and link with database ) and second project is Client side in Visual Studio **Code** ( Angular,  typescript code ).

So two projects under one big project which need to be an online shop where I have products and some images for every product.

**Which is my issue ?**

I can not get the Images already saved in "wwwroot" folder ( in back end - in first project - in Visual Studio ) and display them in Client side ( in Angular - in front end ). I can specify that I have stored images in "wwwroot" folder ( Image Name and the image itself ) and the Image Name and Image Path are saved in the database.
Can you tell me which is the best approach to do get the images from back end and display them in front end ? Can you give me some hint about how to to this ? Give me your approach and how to implement this ?

**What is implemented ?**

In this online shop is implemented inserting of new product ( with Name, Description and also with Image itself ) which is send from front end to back end and stored inside "wwwroot" folder ( Image itself ) and save the Image Name and Image Path inside database.

If is needed I can add some code for better understanding but I need just an approach or an ideea of how to do this.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The content in the wwwroot should be publicly accessible relative to the base URL of your app. As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1) explains:

> Static files are accessible via a path relative to the web root. For
> example, the Web Application project templates contain several folders
> within the wwwroot folder:
>
> - wwwroot
>
>   - css
>   - js
>   - lib
>
> Consider creating the wwwroot/images folder and
> adding the wwwroot/images/MyImage.jpg file. The URI format to access a
> file in the images folder is
> https:///images/<image_file_name>. For example,
> https://localhost:5001/images/MyImage.jpg

So from your Angular app, just use the URLs as expected, like `https://localhost:5001/images/MyImage.jpg` corresponding to `wwwroot/images/MyImage.jpg`.

Comment: This is working even when I have two separates Project ? Meaning I have two separates "wwwroot" folders, one in Visual Studio Code ( Angular - Frontend ) and one in Visual Studio Enterprinse 2019 ( Asp.net core - Backend ). I did not understand yet if this solution is also for case when I have separates project.                                                                                                           I am new in Angular and I can say apologize for eventual misunderstanding and bad phrases.  Thank you, Noah Stahl.

Comment: For purposes of development, the content of your ASP.NET Core project is the webserver and contains everything that you can access via a request from the Angular client. You can always deploy files from other projects, but they have to get served from somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the accepted answer you need to configure your ApplicationBuilder (Configure Methode in Startup.cs):

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Without this your wwwroot folder will not get served. You can also configure UseStaticFiles() with 'StaticFileOptions' to serve a diffrent folder than wwwroot.

Answer (score 4):

An angular .html

```
<img [src]="img"/>
```

Need that

```
img="myimage.jpg"        //if wwwroot/myimage.jpg
img="images/myimage.jpg" //if wwwroot/images/myimage.jpg
```

See that there are not a slash at first.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I tried 20 different things until I finally found a solution.  Here is what you need to do:

1. Create an **images** folder inside the **wwwroot** folder, if you have not already done so.
2. Put the image file into the newly created **images** folder.
3. In the img tag, enter the file path to the image in the following example format:

```
<img src="~/images/mcd-logo.jpg" title="McDonald's Logo" alt="McDonald's Logo" />
```

The big differences for me was putting the images folder in the wwwroot folder and then adding the ~ to the path.

Comment: Apparently this issue depends on the type of project/app you're building.  I just ran into the same problem with an ASP.NET Core MVC application with images not displaying and this is how I had format the SRC:  "/images/delete.png"